# VSCode JSDoc - define dynamic property type

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a class that extends a class from some external code.  In my "constructor", I set a field that the parent uses to make an API call and upon completion, the result gets stored in the `data` property (accessible from my class instance via `this.data`).

How can I tell VSCode via JSDoc comments what the structure of `this.data` is?  I actually create the data structure that returns from the API call so it is known to me.  I have `@typedef`s in my code but I can't seem to properly tell the class what `this.data` looks like.

The best I have been able to do that works is like the below:

```js
class a extends b {
    render() {
        const stuff = /** @type {Stuff} */ (this.data).stuff[1].thing;
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it is only applicable for that particular usage of `this.data`.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around some, it seems the easiest thing to do was to just initialize `this.data` within my classes "constructor" (init method) to an empty string.  Above that initialization I used `@type` to define the structure of it.  I really didn't want to have to add erroneous code to achieve this but I guess it isn't too much.

```js
/** @type {{FOCUS_NOTES: FOCUS_NOTES}} */
this.data = "";
```